# Interesting questions on top

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, sorting

While using stackoverflow i felt its pretty difficult to get my interested questions at one go.I would like to see the questions that i am interested in at the top of the questions list.Or some way so that we can sort the interesting tags based on the "***Level of interest***" and see the most interested questions at the top in a descending order and the ignored tags at the very bottom of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [change to the Stack Overflow homepage took place in November](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) that was designed to bring more interesting questions to the front page, as it is customized for that user. As you'll see, interesting tags are already brought to the top:

> **your interesting tags**    +1,500 per interesting tag, up to +2,000 total

If you don't feel this is enough, the [experimental home page](https://stackoverflow.com/new-home) is still up and you can play around with it to help design your own query, if you're familiar with SQL. (Note that it uses a fixed set of interesting and ignored tags, rather than your own, for testing purposes). Otherwise, you're free to make specific suggestions here on Meta as to what you think could be improved.

You can also click on any tag to see the questions for that tag.

Comment: Very interesting info