# What happened to "order by: interesting"?

Tags: support, sorting, usability, homepage

My normal mode of visiting the site is to refresh the start page and scroll down looking for interesting questions.

This has degraded significantly recently, and the reason seems to be that the start page has reverted to "order by: new" when previously I had it set to "order by: interesting". The dropdown no longer offers this option.

[image: Dropdown screenshot]

Why was it removed? Could it be brought back?

(Do my search skills suck? I could only find questions about interesting *tags*, and then [Interesting questions on top](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73174/interesting-questions-on-top) from 2010.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you accidentally end up on [stackoverflow.com/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) instead of just stackoverflow.com?

The former has a "newest" sort order tab while the latter doesn't. The latter has the "interesting" sort order that is deliberately missing from the /questions page but that otherwise still exists.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks!

Comment: @tripleee Any time. :)

Comment: Now this begs the question why this design exists. Why is there s separate near-identical page? Why does it "deliberately" lack this option?

Comment: @tripleee Stack Overflow is the only site that has the Interesting tab on the front page. It's there because the site gets far too many questions for anyone to either care about all of them or to be able to keep up. So we provide a subset of the questions we think are more likely to be of interest to them. The separate page is the default everywhere else and it *is* occasionally handy. Plus we don't want to make it impossible to get the "normal" question list.

Comment: Take a closer look at the sub-tabs on the front page and on /questions. They fulfill different functions. (Although I agree that the entire navigation is confusing because tabs.)

Comment: Fair enough, and thanks again for the very quick and accurate response.